# How to Solve FRM 41003 :- this function cannot be performed here while opening a form?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

While opening a Oracle form ,It is giving " FRM 41003 This function cannot be performed here ". How could I resolve this error ?

I followed this link :- 
http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/191386 
But It did not help .
In the when-new-form-instance, the following code is here :-

" FDRCSID ('Header: TEMPLATE.fmb 120.0 2005/05/06 23:25  appldev ship                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ');
APP_STANDARD.EVENT('WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE');

Execute_query; "
and in PRE-FORM trigger ,following code I added :- 
"FND_STANDARD.FORM_INFO('Revision: 120.0                                                                                                                                      ', 'Template Form', 'FND',
                       'Date: 2005/05/06 23:25  ', 'Author: appldev ');
app_standard.event('`enter code here`PRE-FORM');
app_window.set_window_position(FORM_NAME, 'FIRST_WINDOW');

```
enter code here
```

Comment: you need to elaborate more as @Littlefoot pointed out. Since, this message may arise for wide range of possible cases.

Answer (score 1):

Which function is "this function"?

Try to click "Help - Display Error" in Forms runtime window - it might reveal the cause.

If not, then - as you got the error while *opening* the form - check `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` and `PRE-FORM` triggers first. If you're unsure of what you see, post their contents here by editing the initial question - don't do that as a comment.

If there's nothing there, then use debug mode (if your Forms version supports it; that would be any version from 9i onwards): create a `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` trigger, put

```
null;
```

command into it and set a breakpoint to that line (right-click the left margin, choose the appropriate action). Run form in debug mode and follow its execution, step-by-step. It'll tell you what's going on.

If you can't debug it, then check PL/SQL procedures (triggers included), comment everything and un-comment command-by-command, until you find the culprit.